# Add a row to table on click of add button the new row is form fields in each cell

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Actually on add click I need to add row its getting added but I am not able to get the ngmodel object Or Is there any other best way to implement using reactive forms so finally requirement is to get a row on add click and get the form value best way of implementation or please modify the above code

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmeklw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check live demo here.

http://keepnote.cc/code/form-group-with-formarray-adding-dyamic-row-angular-5-6

Please check this.

We have to use `FormBuilder` and `FormBuilder.array` for dynamic rows.

### html

```
<form [formGroup]="carForm" (ngSubmit)="saveIntergration()">
    <div formArrayName="details" class="form-group" *ngFor="let field of carForm.get('details').controls; let ind = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="ind">
            Type:
            <input type="text" formControlName="type">

            model:
            <input type="text" formControlName="model">

            year:
            <input type="text" formControlName="year">

            make:
            <input type="text" formControlName="make">

            color
            <input type="text" formControlName="color">

            plateNumber
            <input type="text" formControlName="plateNumber">

            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<button (click)="addRow()">Add New</button>

<pre>
    {{carForm.value | json}}
</pre>
```

### ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html'

})
export class AppComponent {
    public carForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

        const items = [];
        items.push(this.fb.group({
            type: [],
            model: [],
            year: [],
            make: [],
            color: [],
            plateNumber: []
        }));

        this.carForm = this.fb.group({
            details: this.fb.array( items )
        });
    }

    addRow() {
        const details = this.carForm.get('details') as FormArray;
        details.push(this.createItem());
    }

    createItem(): FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group({
            type: [],
            model: [],
            year: [],
            make: [],
            color: [],
            plateNumber: []
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro it worked also my work is done how to make the form displayed only on add click initially I am getting a row is it possible ?

Comment: Cool.! Please accept that answer. In constructor loaded one items.

Comment: Load one item means

Comment: Explain me in details. make the form displayed only on add click initially I am getting a row is it possible

Comment: So before add the form getting initialized is possible to initial after add click

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184375/discussion-between-balaji-v-and-paresh-gami).

Answer (score 0):

> Reactive Forms in Angular: Dynamically Creating Form Fields With `FormArray`.

Please alter your code as per given sample.

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" (click)="addItem()">add</button></div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of data" class="row">
    <div class="col">{{item.Type}}</div>
    <div class="col">{{item.Model}}</div>
    <div class="col">{{item.Year}}</div>
    <div class="col">{{item.Make}}</div>
    <div class="col">{{item.Color}}</div>
    <div class="col">{{item.PlateNumber}}</div>
    <div class="col">{{item.StateRegistered}}</div>
  </div>
  <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;" class="row">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="Type">
      <input formControlName="Model">
      <input formControlName="Year">
      <input formControlName="Make">
      <input formControlName="Color">
      <input formControlName="PlateNumber">
      <input formControlName="StateRegistered">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stack53513269',
  templateUrl: './stack53513269.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stack53513269.component.css']
})
export class Stack53513269Component implements OnInit {
  orderForm: FormGroup;
  items: FormArray;
  data: any = [];
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.data.push({ Type: 'SUV', Model: '500', Year: '2009', Make:'Mahinda',   Color:'Red',    PlateNumber:'RJ-15',    StateRegistered:'Rajsthan' });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
    });
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      Type:'',  Model:'',   Year:'',    Make:'',    Color:'',   PlateNumber:'', StateRegistered:''
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    console.log(this.items.value);
  }
}
```